# C language usage in Scilab Xcos block

Tags: c, gcc, scilab

I have been attempting to get my own Scilab Xcos block written in C language up and running. I have been using Scilab 5.5.2 running on Windows 10 with Cygwin installed. I have started with the freely available tutorial called *ScicosCBlockTutorial* written by Phil Schmidt. I have followed the tutorial and at the point 4.2 I have found that function call

```
ilib_for_link('lim_int','lim_int_comp.o',[],'c','Makelib','loader.sce','','','-g');
```

does not work for me. After a while I have found a solution which works

```
ilib_for_link('lim_int', 'lim_int_comp.c', [], 'c', '', 'loader.sce', '', '', '-g');
```

unfortunately there seems to be some problem with the C language compiler:

```
Generate a loader file
Generate a Makefile
Running the Makefile
 !--error 10000 
A Fortran or C compiler is required.
at line      14 of function ilib_compile called by :  
at line      94 of function ilib_for_link called by :  
ilib_for_link('lim_int', 'lim_int_comp.c', [], 'c', '', 'loader.sce', '', '', '-g');
```

The problem occurs despite the fact that the gcc compiler (gcc (GCC) 9.3.0) is installed on my machine. Does anybody know how to resolve that issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you install gcc on cygwin or directly on your machine

Comment: @snus74 thank you for your reaction. I have installed the gcc as a part of the cygwin. I have just found some guidelines how to proceed in correct way (http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw/0.9.3)

Comment: glad you found your way past this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct procedure how to get C compiler for Scilab up and running is:

1. [download](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw/0.9.3/files/gcc-4.6.3-64.exe) the gcc-4.6.3-64.exe
2. run the gcc-4.6.3-64.exe
3. restart PC
4. open Scilab and invoke `atomsInstall('mingw')`
5. restart Scilab

In case all has been done successfully call of the function `haveacompiler()` from Scilab should return `T`.